# Multi-series Highchart chart from Django

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I've been creating some Highcharts via Django in this fashion:

```
...get rows from database
            rows = cursor.fetchall()

            months = list()
            avg_class = list()

            for i in range(0, len(rows)):
                months.append(rows[i][2])
                avg_class.append(rows[i][5])

            months_j = json.dumps(months, cls=DecimalandDateEncoder)
            avg_class_j = json.dumps(avg_class, cls=DecimalandDateEncoder)
send to my template....
```

Which contains the javascript for the chart in something like this.

```
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                categories: {{ months|safe }},
                etc...........
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Series Name',
                data: {{ avgclassdata }}
            }]
```

This works just fine, with data such as this.

```
Month       Avg Class Data
1/1/2012    17.600493
2/1/2012    18.114341
3/1/2012    16.246443
4/1/2012    16.09489
```

Now, I have data like this:

```
Location    Month   Avg Class Data
Location 1  1/1/2012    17.600493
Location 1  2/1/2012    18.114341
Location 1  3/1/2012    16.246443
Location 1  4/1/2012    16.09489
Location 2  1/1/2012    21.56584
Location 2  2/1/2012    19.54654
Location 2  3/1/2012    17.54654
Location 2  4/1/2012    20.54551
```

This could be any number of locations. And I want to create a Highchart using each location group as a series. I'm at a bit of a loss as how to loop through my rows results and use the location as the series name and then the corresponding average class data as the series data.

My end goal is to create this from my database results:

```
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                categories: {{ months|safe }},
                etc...........
            },
            series: [{
                name: Here would go the name of Location 1,
                data: {{ location 1 data }}
            }, {
                name: Here would go the name of Location 2,
                data: {{ location 2 data }}
            }]
```

I'd prefer just a push in the right direction, rather than somebody just write the code for me. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: May I know what kind of highchart did you use? so that I can make the exact pattern you want

Comment: if you have question regarding to my answer I will answer it tomorrow. Need to sleep :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give it a try. I am using the basic line chart. My main trouble is turning the rows returned by my SQL into the necessary format for Highcharts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     categories: {{ months|safe }},
     etc...........
 },series: [
        {% for location in locations %}
        {
            name: Here would go the name of {{location.name}},
            data: [
               {% for data in location_data %}
               {{data}},
               {% endfor %}
            ]
        },
        {% endfor %}
 ]
```